# Why variable is initialized to undefined eventhough block is not executed?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Variable Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

```
var flag = false;
if(flag === true)
{
     var you = "great";
}
```

Variable "you" is initialized with undefined, it shows undefined instead of showing reference error when printed. why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Javascript, all variables are "hoisted" to the top of the function/scope they're declared in. That is, your code REALLY looks like this to the compiler:

```
var flag = false;
var you;
if (flag === true)
{
    you = "great"
}
```